# Using reflection to create an instance based on getClass of generic class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I would like to know what is the right way to declare `Class<...> stateBaseClass`, when my goal is to create an instance by using Reflection: `state = stateBaseClass.newInstance();` without using cast.

I put some comments in the code below:

```
abstract class StateBase{} // It is so complex to be serializable.

class State extends StateBase{}

class StateInstanceDescription <T extends StateBase> implements Serializable{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -828114417567233018L;

    transient private T stateBase;

    // what is the right way to declare the line below to void that cast?
    private Class<? extends StateBase> stateBaseClass; 

    public StateInstanceDescription(T base){
        this.stateBase = base;
        stateBaseClass = base.getClass();
    }

    public T getBase() {
        return stateBase;
    }

    public Class<? extends StateBase> getBaseClass() {
        return stateBaseClass;
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String ... args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
        State state = new State();
        StateInstanceDescription<State> stateInstDesc = new StateInstanceDescription<>(state);

        // ... At some point, I will recreate State after deserialize stateInstDesc.
        // compiler-time error. Compiler is asking for casting it to (State). 
        // There is a way to avoid this cast?
        state = stateInstDesc.getBaseClass().newInstance(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getBaseClass()` returns a `Class<? extends StateBase>` so the result of `newInstace` can be any subclass of `StateBase` (depending on the class returned). The compiler cannot be sure that this result is specifically of type `State` or from another subclass.

To fix this, work with `Class<T>` and pass this as argument to the constructor of `StateInstanceDescription`:

```
class StateInstanceDescription <T extends StateBase> implements Serializable { 

    transient private T stateBase;

    private Class<T> stateBaseClass; 

    public StateInstanceDescription(T base, Class<T> clazzBase) {
        this.stateBase = base;
        stateBaseClass = clazzBase;
    }

    public T getBase() {
        return stateBase;
    }

    public Class<T> getBaseClass() {
        return stateBaseClass;
    }
}
```

Then in `main`:

```
State state = new State();
StateInstanceDescription<State> stateInstDesc = new StateInstanceDescription<>(state, State.class);

state = stateInstDesc.getBaseClass().newInstance();
```

Comment: But there is another way to declare `private Class<? extends StateBase> stateBaseClass; ` to avoid this cast to State? maybe something like    
`private Class<T> stateBaseClass;`

Comment: It seems like hack-solution. no?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a hack to me. That's how the language works.

Comment: @Paulo where is it a hack?  You are just returning the field with the type it is declared as.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think that it is hack, because you have to use <State> and State.class to create a instance of StateInstanceDescription: `StateInstanceDescription<State> stateInstDesc = new StateInstanceDescription<>(state, State.class);`

Comment: @Paulo generics is a compile time check, but reflection is a runtime task.  At runtime, the JVM doesn't know what generic type you used at compile time so it has to be told what the base class was.  It's not elegant and C# can do this for you, but it not considered a hack in Java because this is the best option.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza If you change the constructor of StateInstanceDescription, and use `stateBaseClass = (Class<T>) base.getClass();` instead of `stateBaseClass = clazzBase;` ? the compile will throw a TypeSafe warning, but I think that it is safe in this case. It isn't more elegant?

Comment: @PeterLawrey please, check my last comment.

Comment: @Paulo it's simpler to work with and you can turn off the warning with `@SuppressWarning("checked")` but if you are going to do that, I would just have `public Class<T> getBaseClass() {
        @SuppressWarning("checked") Class<T> tClass = (Chass<T>) stateBase.getClass(); return tClass;
    }`

Comment: @PeterLawrey i can't use stateBase.getClass(), because stateBase is transient and will be null when i deserialize de StateInstanceDescription

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza How about change the constructor of StateInstanceDescription, and use `stateBaseClass = (Class<T>) base.getClass();` instead of `stateBaseClass = clazzBase;` ?